# How can I determine the owner of a Sql Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server

There seem to be easy ways to find the version of a SQL Server instance, and other useful information.  I need to find out who owns the SQL Server instance.  Is there a query that can find this?

Comment: How do you define "instance owner"? I'm not sure this is a standard terminology in MS SQL world.

Comment: Each instance has an owner, some administrator name.  I'm working on a situation where the owner name can sometimes be changed, and I need to know that.

Answer (score 1):

select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases

Or want just a specific database?

select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases where name = 'the database name'